# Cordova File Chooser To Allow Multiple Mime Types

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, capacitor

I want to filter 'PDF', 'WORD' and 'TEXT' only while choosing file from FileChooser.

If I pass a single Mime type like below, it works:

```
FileChooser.open({"mime":'application/pdf'})
```

But how can i filter multiple multiple mime types at singe open function, any opther similar plugin from Ionic/Cordova or CapacitorJS?
I tried passing like array also, but doesn't worked.

```
FileChooser.open({"mime":['application/pdf', 'text/plain', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document']})
```

Comment: check this link "https://github.com/PeterHdd/cordova-filechooser" i think you need to write `{ "mime": "image/jpeg, application/pdf" };` like this

Comment: @RaviAshara, No it didn't worked too